# How to convert rows that contain same value for one column but different for other columns into one single row using R?

Tags: r, subset

I have data as follows :

```
User_Id      Website      Day
A        Google    Monday
A        Facebook   Tuesday
A        Linkedin    Wednesday
B        Facebook   Tuesday
B       Linkedin    Wednesday
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
User_ID   Google  Facebook  Linkedin  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday
A        1       1         1          1       1        1
B        0       1         1          0       1        1
```

The columns now represent the number of times it is appearing for each users.
How can I do this in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `unlist` the 2nd and 3rd column of `data.frame` (`unlist(df1[-1]`) and replicate the 1st column by the number of other columns i.e. in this case 2 (`rep(df1[,1], 2)`), get the frequency count with `table` and convert to a `data.frame` (`as.data.frame.matrix`).

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(rep(df1[,1],2), unlist(df1[-1])))
#  Facebook Google Linkedin Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#A        1      1        1      1       1         1
#B        1      0        1      0       1         1
```

---

If we need a package solution, another option is `dplyr/tidyr`.  Reshape the 'wide' to 'long' format with `gather` (from `tidyr`), get the frequency `count` and `spread` back to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    gather(Var, Val, -User_Id) %>%
    count(User_Id, Val) %>% 
    spread(Val, n, fill = 0)   
#   User_Id Facebook Google Linkedin Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#    <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#1       A        1      1        1      1       1         1
#2       B        1      0        1      0       1         1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @akrun. Can you break that code and explain me what it does ? I am a beginner.

Comment: @RohitKadam Updated the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was searching for a solution for this since last two days. Finally got it .

Answer (score 2):

An option with `reshape2::recast` which basically first converts all the columns to a long format by `User_Id` and then spreads back according to `User_Id` again

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, User_Id ~ value, id.var = "User_Id", length)
#   User_Id Facebook Google Linkedin Monday Tuesday Wednesday
# 1       A        1      1        1      1       1         1
# 2       B        1      0        1      0       1         1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. This worked too. Can I ask you how does it strike at first instance that this can be achieved using this particular package and then the code of it ?

Comment: Usually by experience. This type of question was asked many times already on SO. Usually when you are trying to reshape your data you should look into `reshape2`/`tidyr`/`data.table` packages and Google "reshape R" or "long to wide r" and similar. Or just look into akruns answers :)

Comment: Hey David, whenever I use this, there is a column next to userid named "Var.2" that creeps in. Any reason for this ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.